# Stop audio play() when there is audio div in HTML

Tags: javascript

I have a `<div onclick="startSound">` in HTML. When clicked, it triggers a sound. How can I make it stop the first sound and play another one when clicked again? Most solutions I found use the `<audio>` HTML tag, but since there is none, how to do it?

```
function startSound() {
         var musicPlay=new Audio('sound.mp3');
         musicPlay.play();     
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You should have a single audio element, every time you click on a certain element, instead of creating a new `Audio` component, change the `src` property of the existing Audio component.
>   To stop the existing Audio that is in `playing` state, `sound.pause();sound.currentTime = 0;` would help.

```js
let myAudio = document.getElementById('myAudio');

function startSound() {
  myAudio.pause();
  myAudio.currentTime = 0;
  myAudio.src = 'sound.mp3';
}
```

```html
<audio controls id="myAudio">
  <source src="anotherSound.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```